# how do I determin the length of a char list filled with Strings without using ANY String methods and NO imports

Tags: java, list, function, string-length

I have an array like this:

```
MyString str = new MyString(new char[]{'a','b','c','d'});
```

`MyString` is **not** important for the question.

This is what I tried so far:

```
 public int length()
 {


String s = ""; 

for (int i = 0; i<data.length; i++)
 s = s+data[i];
```

data has the list with strings in it.

```
 int i = 0; 
 try 
 {

 for(i=0; ; i++)
 {
   s.charAt(i);
 }

 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {

 }

return  i;

}
```

This method I am using is working but uses `charAt(i)`; which is not allowed. How could I try this according to the rules in my question?

```
--> expected output: str.length(); // 6
```

Comment: If you have an array of characters, why not just use the length of the array?  some better explanation would help.  But you can't find the length of a string without using String methods.  You need to invoke the method `String.toCharArray()` to get the array from the string.  And why is the length 6 when you only have 4 characters?

Answer (score 1):

You can catch an array out of bounds exception.

```java
      char[] a = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'
      };

      int length = -1;
      try {
         for (;;) {
            char c = a[++length];
         }
      }
      catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ae) {
      }
      System.out.println("length = " + length);
```

Note:  This is not a good way to use of exceptions.  And as I said before, if you have the array, then just use `array.length`.